# Compatibility for Sharepoint with IE11 and JRE 1.7

Tags: upgrade

We are trying to upgrade our IE from IE9-IE11 and Java JRE1.6 to 1.7 . Is SharePoint compatible with IE 11 and JRE 1.7 And are any patches needed for the IE and java to  run without any problems

Comment: Please tag SharePoint version

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 support IE 8, 9, 10 & 11.

Please check the browser support matrix http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.15).aspx

For JRE you should check if some custom Java Applets are loaded into SharePoint application or not. Else you don't need to worry with JRE.